# VS code giving "identifier not defined" error on usage of angular async and elvis operator with observable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, asynchronous, visual-studio-code

I am getting the red underlined warning message in `VScode` editor saying the identifier "frProfileData" is not defined, but the chrome console is showing not errors.
I am using `async` pipe with `elvis` operator, which is why the identifiers must be resolved after `async` request is fulfilled.
Please help me out with this issue.
[image: my VScode html template screenshot with warning]

[image: VScode typescript file screenshot]

MY TYPESCRIPT CODE:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 import { FundraiserLoadService } from '../../../services/fundraiser-
 load.service'
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-fr-profile',
   templateUrl: './fr-profile.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./fr-profile.component.css']
 })
 export class FrProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 responseData: Observable<object>;
 frLoadProfSubscr: Subscription;
 constructor(
 private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
 private _router: Router,
 private _frLoadSerivice: FundraiserLoadService
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 let frName = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['frname']
 this.responseData = this._frLoadSerivice.getFrProfile(frName)

        }

 }
```

My HTML CODE:

```
<div  class="on-load accent-gray-light">
    <div class="container title-div">
        <h1 class="text-gray">
            <strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.title}}</strong>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container outer-container">

        <!-- ######################################## ROW ONE #############################################-->

        <div class="row row-wrapper">
            <!-- ########### LEFT ################-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 row1-left">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-responsive fr-img" [src]="(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.imagePath[0]" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- ########### RIGHT ################-->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 row1-right">
                <!--  LOCATION AND CATEGORY -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-gray-l location" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9">
                    <p class="h5 pull-left">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;
                        <strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.city}}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h5 pull-right">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>&nbsp;
                        <strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.category}}</strong>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <!--  AMOUNT RAISED AND PROGRESS -->
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div style="margin:20px 0px 0px 0px ;padding:5px 0px">
                        <p class="bold-numbers-gr" style="margin:0px">Rs.{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.amountRaised}}</p>
                        <p class="text-gray-l" style="margin:0px;font-size:1.2em">Raised of {{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.amountToRaise}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Progress Bar -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 pr-br-wpr">
                    <div style="margin: 0px;padding:0px">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar accent-light" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Supporters -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 supporters-div ">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left" style="margin: 0px;padding:0px">
                        <h2>
                            <strong>67</strong>
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Supporters</strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right" style="margin: 0px;padding:0px">
                        <h2>
                            <strong>34</strong>
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Days left</strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- DONATE-->
                <div class="col-xs-12 btn-wrapper text-center">
                    <button class="btn donate-btn button-accent" type="button">
                        <span style="font-size:1.3em">
                            <strong>Donate Now</strong>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <p class="input-caption ">Payment options: Account number</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- ######################################## ROW TWO #############################################-->

        <div class="row row-wrapper">
            <!-- ########### LEFT ################-->            
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 row2-left">
                <h3 class="text-center special-heading">STORY</h3>
                <p class="lead">{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.story}}</p>

                <br/><br/>
                <h3><strong>Account Name: </strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.accName}}</h3>
                <h3><strong>Bank Name: </strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.bankName}}</h3>
                <h3><strong>Account No: </strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.accNo}}</h3>
                <h3><strong>IFSC code: </strong>{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.ifsc}}</h3>
            </div>




            <!-- ########### RIGHT ################-->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4  row2-right">
                <div class="started-by accent-gray-light">
                    <p class="h5">
                        <strong>Campaign By:&nbsp;{{(responseData | async)?.frProfileData[0]?.registeredUserData?.name}}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <hr style="border:0.5px solid #c9c9c9">
                    <p class="h5">
                        <strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h5">
                        <strong>
                         2 Campaigns | 4 Donated
                        </strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   <!-- ########### ROW TWO END ################-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are using some extensions

Comment: extensions like what ?.I dont get it

Comment: visual studio extensions

Comment: I have similar extensions that give suggestions in template file

Comment: do one thing disable all extensions in visual studio code and then check the template file

Comment: i installed "Angular language Service" extension few days back but i did not used async pipe back then,  this extension might be the issue.

Comment: May be this extensions is creating the problem

Comment: disable this extensions and then try

Comment: Disabling "angular language extension" fixed the issue. this was the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

You have installed `"Angular language service"` which was causing this issue.
Disabled this extensions and reload the visual studio code.

Comment: Okey, but by disabling this extension you loose all functionality which extension offers like completions lists, quick info about component properties, etc...

Answer (score -4):

Ok the issue was resolved by the solution given by [santosh singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449897/santosh-singh) in the comments.

There was an extension namely "Angular language service" which was causing this annoying thing.I simply disabled it and reloaded my VS code window, the warning was gone then.

Comment: You should accept his answer as correct instead of adding another answer to say he is correct